# Formatting dates in an MVC Dropdown

Tags: date, model-view-controller, html-select

I have a dropdown list on my page as so: -

```
@Html.DropDownList("dd_dates", new SelectList(@Model.seasonDates), "Please Select")
```

where seasonDates is an IList of dates. The problem is that when the dates are displayed in the dropdown they also have the time on them as well. How do I format the display date so that the time is not included.

Comment: You need to do that in seasonDates() function

Comment: It's just a property in the view model that contains an list of dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a better way to do this would be to define a property in your model that returns `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (in your model class):

```
public DateTime SelectedDate {get;set;}

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SeasonDates
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var item in seasonDates)
            yield return new SelectListItem() 
            { 
                Text = item.ToShortDateString(), // or apply your own formatting!
                Value = item
             };
    }
}
```

Then use this in the view:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDate, @Model.SeasonDates, "Please Select")`

Apologies if there are errors, I dont have VS open to verify the sytanx.